# How to use android databinding binding events

Tags: android, events, data-binding

I use android databinding to binding Button click events,but I can't do it .I need help. 
this is my Xml:

```
<data>

    <import type="com.test.databindingdemo.MyHandler" />

    <variable
        name="handlers"
        type="MyHandler" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{handlers.handleClick}" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my code:

```
public class MyHandler {
    public void handleClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "you clicked the view", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

this is my Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainlayoutBinding mainlayoutBinding=DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.mainlayout);
        mainlayoutBinding.setHandlers(new MyHandler());
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly is going wrong? Do you get any errors? What are those errors? What have you tried to do to fix those errors? What happened when you did that? Remember to include these things when you make your question. Follow this guide to make sure your questions are of high quality: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the code you posted. To be sure about that I created a [Sample Project](https://github.com/arsent/AndroidBindingSample) using your code and it works fine. It shows the Toast message when you click on the button.

Comment: I also tried just now,no error, I don't know why I can't  run it yesterday! Anyway thank you all the same!!!